# Exception has occurred. _CastError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

Am trying to get an FCM Token using

```
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
const String firebaseCloudvapidKey = "MY_PUBLIC_KEY_IS_HERE";

_firebaseMessaging.getToken(vapidKey: firebaseCloudvapidKey).then((val) async {
        print('Token: ' + val);
});
```

This is the error i get whenever i run this
[image: flutter]

Am using genymotion emulator and i don't know where the error is coming from please help me out and if you need more explanation tell me i will add to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `print('Token: ' + val);` the val here is a `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`. You need to access the key of they value you need.
You can type `print('Token: ' + $val);` to see how it looks like.

Comment: Nope that isn't the problem. It doesn't work

Comment: What error are you getting now? It can't be the same error.

Comment: The error in the image is what am getting and i don't really know where it coming from

Comment: This is working without errors for me,  `await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken(vapidKey: 'hii').then((value) => print('Token: ' + value));`

Comment: Ok i found out the problem its from my emulator after using a physical device there was no error. But thank you very much

Comment: Ok i found out the problem its from my emulator after using a physical device there was no error. But thank you very much

Comment: You're most welcome, if my answer was helpful, kindly consider marking it as an answer.